# Python TCP Server Doesnt Work on LAN or WAN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

**TL;DR:** Python TCP server can't access LAN or WAN

I programmed a TCP server using python 3. It works normally on localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1200 using both Telnet and client program but when I try from another computer on the network or from another computer on the internet, it fails with both client or Telnet as if there wasn't any server up.

I am behind a router, so do I have to set up something like port forwarding or something? Or is there something wrong with my code? I also tried turning off my firewall.

---

Here's the **server** :

```
import socket
import time
import sys
import Clients

Port = 1200
MaxConnections = 5

try :
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except :
    
    print("Something Went Wrong Creating The Scoket and Going to exit.")
    sys.exit()

    #Bind on The Connection Port
    sock.bind(("",Port))
    print("")
    
    #Listen to Connections 
    sock.listen(MaxConnections)
    print("")
    

while True:
    client,addr = sock.accept()
    Clients.AddClient(client)
    print("")
    rcName = client.recv(1024)
    print(rcName.decode('ascii'),"Connected to Server", addr  , time.ctime(time.time()))
```

And this is the Clients.py that I imported in the server :

```
Clients = []



def AddClient (ClientAdress) :
    Clients.append(ClientAdress)
```

---

And here is the **Client** :

```
import socket
from socket import *
import urllib
import sys
import os 
import time
import string

serverIp = str(input("Enter The Server Ip Adress : "))
serverPort = int(input("ENter The Server's Port : "))
name = "MyName"

#Creating Sockets
sock = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

try :
        sock.connect((serverIp,serverPort))
        
except :
    print("Failed to Connect to Server")
    sys.exit

#This Part Sends The Name of The Client to The Serevr

data = name

sock.send(data.encode('ascii'))
print("")
print ("    ----------------------   Connected to Server   ----------------------   ")
while True :
     #Wont Do ANything for Now cuz i Removed The Sending Mesage Part from The Server
     rCData = sock.recv(1024)
     print (rcData)
```

---

The server for now only prints the name of the connected client and its IP and the time.

I commented out the part of sending messages for some problems. I don't think there's a problem with the code since it works normally on localhost.

Comment: Could you please try and strip down your code to it's bare essentials? For example the decorative print calls are unnecessary- but try to give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlexThornton 
Done :) .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the IP address of the server in the server code so it binds to the correct adapter.

```
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())   
s.bind((HOST, Port))
```

Comment: Sorry This Didnt Work :\
Still Same Problem
Anyways Thanks For Help 
and Btw I Made The Code Easier To Read Now

Comment: I am also suspecting bind to be the issue. Can you explicitly bind to the server_ip instead of gethostbyname? The same server IP which you pass as command line argument in the client. ALSO, make sure the serverIP is pingable from cleint.